# make Nodes of d3.js collapsible/expandable for a hierarchy graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I had a requirement that the level 1 of the tree ( assuming root is 0th level) should fit in the view, ideally should be responsive. which I got. But the challenge is to make the level 1 children expandable/collapsible ( the tree shouldn't need to be responsive after level 1)

1. They should expand relative to their parents i.e should appear just below the clicked parent and the graph should adjust accordingly. I added the zoom feature for that),  please refer to Level2: children which are nested.

Also it is tricky to make it as recursive. I added the click
functionality but is not working. Here is the working link.

I am using D3 version 5.7.0

https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-agjbrb?file=index.js,index.html,package.json